# submit a form with flags, radiobuttons, input using Spring and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring

I have a problem.
I have to do a web site with a search box with a form, like this:

```
RADIOBUTTON 1 (if it is selected SEARCHBY = 1) - INPUT 1 (box with text to insert = texttosearch)
RADIOBUTTON 2 (if it is selected SEARCHBY = 2) - INPUT 2 (box with text to insert = texttosearch)
RADIOBUTTON 3 (if it is selected SEARCHBY = 3) - INPUT 3 (box with text to insert = texttosearch)
FLAG 1 (value y if it is selected)
FLAG 2 (value y if it is selected)
```

I have to use the Spring form:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="searchmodel">
<form:input path="texttosearch"/>
<form:input path="searchby"/>
<form:radiobutton path="flag1" value="Y"/>
<form:radiobutton path="flag2" value="Y"/>
</form:form>
```

These parameters are useful to choose the right query in my controller for searching results.
I have to use JQUERY:

```
$("#searchform").click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        var form = $("form#searchModelTracciabilita");
        form.find("input[path=texttosearch]").val();
        form.find("radiobutton[path=flag1]").val();
```

...}

My code doesn't work, any suggestions?
Thank you so much!

Comment: excuse me,there is an error in JQuery: var form = $("form#searchmodel") instead of searchModelTracciabilita

Comment: You can edit the question rather than adding comments. The `My code doesn't work` won't help. Describe exact results - errors, messages, logs, debug results and expected results.